# How to keep data in memory to dynamic query next data income Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am doing time series data analysis in Flink with DataStream API. Every 50 events (data income) I would like to make a transformation with them, save the result and compare it with the result of the transformation from the next 50 events. And so on and so forth. 
My question is, is there a way in Flink, after doing a transformation, to save the results, and query the next transformation of the next 50 events, with the previous results?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a couple of ways to do this, both leveraging Flink state.

(1) You can use count windows that use `globalState()` in the `ProcessAllWindowFunction.Context` to remember information about the previous window(s). ([docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#using-per-window-state-in-processwindowfunction))

(2) Or you can implement the windowing yourself with a `RichFlatMapFunction` or a `ProcessFunction`. In this case you'll need to create and manage the necessary [state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/) yourself, but that's not difficult. You'd need a counter, some representation of the results of the previous window, and the current window.

In both cases you'll need to be working with a keyed stream. If you need to do this globally, rather than on a key-partitioned stream, let me know and I'll follow up.

Comment: Thanks, let me try the different approaches and I will be back to you.